# How to clear Android fragment back stack without resuming intermediate fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to clear all fragments from the back stack.

The problem is I need to make sure at some point of time, the stack has been successfully cleared and none of the popped back fragments will be resumed afterwards.

Some fragments display content which is related to the currently signed in user.
Now if the user decides to sign out, I would like to clear the stack, sign out the user and transition the app to the initial fragment.
The problem is, the stack pop is deferred and after I sign out, some user related fragments try to resume and ask for user profile data. And the underlying API throws an exception if there is no signed in user. So the fragment crashes as it should not be used in such state.

I have tried many ways:

```
@Override
public void onSignOutConfirmed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSignOutConfirmed");

    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    Log.d(TAG, "onSignOutConfirmed - signing out");

    UserProfileService.signOut();
    Analytics.trackEvent(EventType.SIGN_OUT);
    showStartupScreen();
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onSignOutConfirmed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSignOutConfirmed");

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    int backStackCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();

    while(backStackCount-- != 0) {
        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onSignOutConfirmed - signing out");

    UserProfileService.signOut();
    Analytics.trackEvent(EventType.SIGN_OUT);
    showStartupScreen();
}
```

The log reveals that the fragment is still processing its lifecycle methods when I call UserProfileService.signOut(). The AsyncTask that retrieves the profile data for one of the fragments is cancelled (with interrupt) when the fragment is paused. But the fragment is paused too late.

And the error doesn't always hit. But most of the times it hits on Samsung S2 (Android 4.1.2).

```
06-09 19:46:54.760 D/com.myapp.application.MainActivity( 4562): **onSignOutConfirmed**
06-09 19:46:54.765 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.MainFragment( 4562): onCreateView
06-09 19:46:54.826 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.MainFragment( 4562): onCreateAnimation (transit 0, enter true, nextAnim 0)
06-09 19:46:54.831 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.TranscriptionsFragment( 4562): onCreateView
06-09 19:46:54.856 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.MainFragment( 4562): onResume
06-09 19:46:54.856 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.TranscriptionsFragment( 4562): **onResume**
06-09 19:46:54.866 D/com.myapp.application.MainActivity( 4562): **onSignOutConfirmed - signing out**
06-09 19:46:54.876 D/myappDB( 4562): Application settings: id 1.
06-09 19:46:54.876 D/myappDB( 4562): Application settings (id 1): updated, [_activeProfileId] = [null].
06-09 19:46:54.916 D/myappDB( 4562): Application settings: active user profile null.
06-09 19:46:54.941 D/myappDB( 4562): Application settings: active user profile null.
06-09 19:46:54.951 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.TranscriptionsFragment( 4562): **onPause**
06-09 19:46:54.951 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.MainFragment( 4562): onPause
06-09 19:46:54.961 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.TranscriptionsFragment( 4562): onDestroyView
06-09 19:46:54.961 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.MainFragment( 4562): onDestroyView
06-09 19:46:54.961 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.MainFragment( 4562): onCreateAnimation (transit 0, enter false, nextAnim 0)
06-09 19:46:55.381 E/AndroidRuntime( 4562):     at com.myapp.application.impls.sqlite.SQLiteApplicationSettingsPersistance.getAndCheckActiveUserProfileId(SQLiteApplicationSettingsPersistance.java:421)
06-09 19:46:55.381 E/AndroidRuntime( 4562):     at com.myapp.application.impls.sqlite.SQLiteTranscriptionPersistance.getTranscriptionStats(SQLiteTranscriptionPersistance.java:54)
06-09 19:46:55.381 E/AndroidRuntime( 4562):     at com.myapp.application.impls.finders.TranscriptionListFinder.getTranscriptions(TranscriptionListFinder.java:45)
06-09 19:46:55.381 E/AndroidRuntime( 4562):     at com.myapp.application.screens.main.TranscriptionsFragment$RetrieveTranscriptionsAsyncTask.doInBackground(TranscriptionsFragment.java:244)
06-09 19:46:55.381 E/AndroidRuntime( 4562):     at com.myapp.application.screens.main.TranscriptionsFragment$RetrieveTranscriptionsAsyncTask.doInBackground(TranscriptionsFragment.java:241)
06-09 19:46:55.421 D/com.myapp.application.screens.main.TranscriptionsFragment( 4562): onDetach
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html  SCROLL down, check the "lifecycle" graphic and note 4 callbacks in fragment when u resume it -  where you can catch the fact that theres no "CURRENT-USER"

Comment: But I don't want to deal with the abnormal situation in each and every fragment. It would pollute many fragments with unnecessary code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void clearFragmentBackStack() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
}
```